# Vertically split one column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to split column `hobbies` by comma from the following dataframe, then vertically set them respectively:

```
   id   name       hobbies
0   1   John  TV, computer
1   2  Steve  travel, film
2   3    Jim     swim, jog
```

How could I get an output like this? Thank you.

```
   id   name   hobbies
0   1   John        TV
1   1   John  computer
2   2  Steve    travel
3   2  Steve      film
4   3    Jim      swim
5   3    Jim       jog
```

Comment: Use `explode` for version 0.25+ here after splitting the string on comma: `out = df.assign(hobbies=df['hobbies'].str.split(',')).explode('hobbies')` for lower version of pandas , use `m = df.assign(hobbies=df['hobbies'].str.split(','))` and then `out = m.loc[m.index.repeat(m['hobbies'].str.len())].assign(hobbies=np.concatenate(m['hobbies']))`

Comment: Thank you, I’ll test with my data and let you know.

Comment: It works perfect, you may answer the question with it if you like to.

Comment: That's okay as this has been asked before, I have closed it.